# Which one is most cost expensive to solve a linear equation? LU or inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, gaussian-elimination, lu-decomposition

Which one is the most expensive way to solve for linear equation? 
LU-decomposition
$$A = LU$$

Or finding the inverse
$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)} \operatorname{adj}(A)$$

If I have to choose, I would say that this equation
$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)} \operatorname{adj}(A)$$

Is much faster than compute LU-factorization. Why? Well, I wrote a linear algebra library in C, which I'm going to upload on GitHub very soon.
First I find the determiannt, by using gaussian elemination. Very smooth and easy method. If I divide with zero, I just change that zero to a very small number so I don't get an error.

Then I find the minor matrix. Which also is a easy method to do, nummericaly. 
Example:

$$M_{2,3} = \det \begin{bmatrix}
\,\,1 & 4 & \Box\, \\
\,\Box & \Box & \Box\, \\
-1 & 9 & \Box\, \\
\end{bmatrix}= \det \begin{bmatrix}
\,\,\,1 & 4\, \\
-1 & 9\, \\
\end{bmatrix} = (9-(-4)) = 13$$

Then I change the minor matrix to cofactor matrix just by multiply them with $-1$. Easy! Divide $1$ with the determiant and multiply it with the cofactor matrix. Then I got the inverse.

But with LU-factorization, in code, I first need to find $L$ and $U$ from $A$, then I need to solve this linear equation 
$$Ax = b$$

Which can be described as

$$LUx = b$$

and then I need to solve these two equations

$$Ly = b$$
$$Ux = y$$

That requries more for-loops in C code, than finding the determiant with Gaussian elimination and finding the minor matrix.

Or am I wrong?

Comment: To fairly compare, I think you'd need to include the matrix multiplication $A^{-1}b$, which for large $A$ could be significant. Solving the forward and backward substitutions using the $LU$ factorization is generally faster than the matrix multiplication (especially for large matrices) and there are a number of other reasons to prefer $LU$ factorizations numerically.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall Okey. Thank you for the answer. If you got the answer, you can post it here and I will accept it.

Comment: Can I compute the determinant too with LU? Even the inverse too?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say it's a complete answer, which is why I posted it as a comment. There is potentially much more to discuss.
$\DeclareMathOperator{tr}{tr}$
The determinant is easy: $\det (A)=\det(L)\det(U)=\tr(L)\tr(U)$. Finding the inverse is a matter of solving the system $LUx=b$ for each of the unit vectors $e_i$, which is rather inexpensive.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall $\det(L)\det(U) = \operatorname{tr}(L)\operatorname{tr}(U)$ sounds wrong... What if $L$ and $U$ are both the unit matrix?

Comment: Oh, my bad. True. Not the trace (the sum of the diagonals) but rather the *product* of the diagonals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performing Gaussian elimination on a matrix of size $m \times m$ takes $\mathcal{O}(m^3)$ operations. To find the cofactor matrix of a $n \times n$ matrix you need to calculate $n^2$ determinants of $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrices. If you don't find any way to take advantage of previous work that takes $n^2 \mathcal{O}((n-1)^3) = \mathcal{O}(n^5)$ operations.

Computing a LU-decomposition of that $n \times n$ matrixtakes $\frac23 n^3$ operations in leading order (so in particular $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ operations). Therefore calculating the LU-decomposition is clearly faster than the method you are currently using for calculating the inverse.
(My argument only shows this for large enough $n$, but I'm very sure a detailed analysis will show that LU-decomposition is faster for basically any size.)

Note however that you can use Gauß elimination to directly calculate the inverse of a matrix, without the costly computation of the adjoint, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix). If my calculation is correct this requires $\frac56 n^3$ operations in leading order so it is still a bit slower than LU-decomposition.

In theory the [Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) or [even faster algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) for matrix multiplication give rise to matrix inversion algorithms that is even faster than $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$, but only for **very** large matrices.

**Summary:** LU-decomposition is the fastest way to solve a reasonably sized system of linear equations and superior to calculating inverses in almost all aspects. In particular performing the multiplication $A^{-1} x$ is as expensive as solving the linear equations $L y = b$ and $U x = y$, since this can be done very efficiently using forward/backward substitution.